# How to convert JSON into associative/indexed array

Tags: json, go

Given this JSON

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name" : "Elliot",
      "type" : "Reader",
      "age" : 23,
      "social" : {
        "facebook" : "https://facebook.com",
        "twitter" : "https://twitter.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "name" : "Fraser",
      "type" : "Author",
      "age" : 17,
      "social" : {
        "facebook" : "https://facebook.com",
        "twitter" : "https://twitter.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need a function/library to return a **map** in order to do `myMap[0].name`  to get the value "Elliot".
Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Show what you tried so far. If you are having trouble getting started, see [this example in the encoding/json doc](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#example-Unmarshal). Also, do you want a map or a slice? The title says associative/indexed array and the body says map

Comment: A slice would be the normal way to unmarshal a JSON array, and will let you do `Users[0].Name`.

Comment: I got a config.json, I put the entire content into map[string]interface{}, but the problem comes when I write Res["users"][0] in order to take the first object. it wants I iterate the interface{} with a range, and fetch all fields, but I wish to access to that field in much beautiful notation associative-array like Res["users"][0].Name, or something like that. I want to replace all interface{} field (like the object) with a map (being a collection of users I want map[int]map[string]string for the single user)

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to access to that field in much beautiful notation associative-array like Res["users"][0].Name, or something like that.

As mentioned in comments, arguably the **nicest** way would be using structs

```golang
type User struct {
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Type   string `json:"type"`
    Age    int    `json:"age"`
    Social struct {
        Facebook string `json:"facebook"`
        Twitter  string `json:"twitter"`
    } `json:"social"`
}
type Config struct {
    Users []User `json:"users"`
}


rawJSON := []byte(`{...your config JSON in here...}`)

config := Config{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(rawJSON, &config); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

user := config.Users[0]

fmt.Printf(
    "name: %s, type: %s, age: %d, facebook: %s, twitter: %s\n",
    user.Name,
    user.Type,
    user.Age,
    user.Social.Facebook,
    user.Social.Twitter,
)
```

Result:

```
name: Elliot, type: Reader, age: 23, facebook: https://facebook.com, twitter: https://twitter.com
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AvKWWaa6WAZ)

Comment: OK! That's great! But I just want 1) to do that without struct (if it's possible), and 2) put that code in a function that return config, in this example. I tried but I had problem about the return type (because config is not always the same type), maybe we can hack this problem using pointer? In brief I want to do something as much flexible as possible, without struct and for every return type.

Comment: The problem with return type is sometimes config is map[int]map[string]string, and other times is map[string]string (simple JSON).